# how to access the girdpane columns and rows in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I build a gridpane in scenebuilder.I have a image view in every cell.I want to build a dynamic gallery pictures.I want to remove the last image in every row and add it to the first column in next row?How can I do it?I am beginer in javafx, please help me :(
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
// if you know how many columns you have (and their indexes) this step is unnecessary:
int minColIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE ;
int maxColIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE ;
for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    int colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
    if (colIndex < minColIndex) minColIndex = colIndex ;
    if (colIndex > maxColIndex) maxColIndex = colIndex ;
}

// Update row and column indexes:
for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    int colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
    if (colIndex == maxColIndex) {
        int rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(node, rowIndex+1);
        GridPane.setColIndex(node, minColIndex);
    } else {
        GridPane.setColIndex(node, colIndex + 1) ;
    }
}
```

Are you sure a [TilePane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) wouldn't suit your needs better, though?

Comment: Thank you for your help,I want to build a gallery pictures like this:  (http://www.uifaces.com) I bind the second slider to the grid pane Hgap and vgap,but I have a fixed size,so when I increase the grid gap I should add some rows and move the imagenode in grid to them sequentially,please help me.